# Parse variable, change value then update parsed variable

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
class quizWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.ui = Ui_Quiz()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        
        conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Questions')
        record = cursor.fetchall()

        #Work out the total number of points available for the quiz by looping through each record and adding the each questions point values together      
        totPoints = 0
        for element in record:
            totPoints = totPoints + element[3]
        
        runTot = 0

        self.ui.txtQuestion1.setText(record[0][1])
        self.ui.txtPoints1.setText(str(record[0][3]))
        self.ui.txtQuestion2.setText(record[1][1])
        self.ui.txtPoints2.setText(str(record[1][3]))
        self.ui.txtQuestion3.setText(record[2][1])
        self.ui.txtPoints3.setText(str(record[2][3]))
        self.ui.txtScore2.setText(str(totPoints))
        self.ui.btnSubmit1.clicked.connect(lambda x: self.subAns(record, runTot, 1, 0))
        self.ui.btnSubmit2.clicked.connect(lambda x: self.subAns(record, runTot, 2, 1))
        self.ui.btnSubmit3.clicked.connect(lambda x: self.subAns(record, runTot, 3, 2))
        self.ui.btnLogout.clicked.connect(self.logout)
        self.ui.btnHome.clicked.connect(self.loadHome) 
    
    def loadHome(self):
        homePage.show()
        quizPage.hide()

    def logout(self):
        quizPage.hide()
        loginPage.show()
    
    def subAns(self, record, runTot, qnum, recInd): 
        txtAns = getattr(self.ui, f'txtAnswer{qnum}').text()
        if txtAns == record[recInd][2]:
            runTot = runTot+record[recInd][3]
            getattr(self.ui,f'btnSubmit{qnum}').setEnabled(False)
            self.ui.txtScore1.setText(str(runTot))
            getattr(self.ui, f'txtAnswer{qnum}').setEnabled(False)
            
            return runTot

        else:
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.critical(self,'Incorrect','That is not the correct answer')
```

Everything works perfectly except the `runTot` variable resets to 0 each time one of the submit buttons is clicked. I know that this is probably because I am setting it to 0 in the `___init___` function, but I don't know how else to manage this variable. I dont get why the return statement is not updating it. Would I need to do something like `runTot = subAns()` for that to happen? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: Why not use a class attribute?

Comment: The `lambda`s are all referencing the same `runTot` local variable which disappears when the `__init__()` method returns. You need to use something more permanent like a class attribute.

Comment: Ohhh... my apologies! I have actually used a class. Perhaps I should repost a wider scope of my code. I have amended it now. So this class is a part of a much larger python module which contains other classes relevant for the different "pages" I have for my application. This is the quiz "page"

Comment: Precisely the same problem still exists in the code in your updated question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use self to do that.

Edited Code:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Questions")
    record = cursor.fetchall()

    self.runTot = 0

    self.ui.btnSubmit1.clicked.connect(lambda x: self.subAns(record, self.runTot, 1, 0))
    self.ui.btnSubmit2.clicked.connect(lambda x: self.subAns(record, self.runTot, 2, 1))
    self.ui.btnSubmit3.clicked.connect(lambda x: self.subAns(record, self.runTot, 3, 2))


def subAns(self, record, runTot, qnum, recInd):
    txtAns = getattr(self.ui, f"txtAnswer{qnum}").text()
    if txtAns == record[recInd][2]:
        self.runTot = runTot + record[recInd][3]
        getattr(self.ui, f"btnSubmit{qnum}").setEnabled(False)
        self.ui.txtScore1.setText(str(self.runTot))
        getattr(self.ui, f"txtAnswer{qnum}").setEnabled(False)

        return self.runTot

    else:
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.critical(
            self, "Incorrect", "That is not the correct answer"
        )
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.